Issue in Adding Token Metadata using SPL Token CLI
I have created a new SPLToken on DevNet and added the following account - 2ePFwPK3coTPqzirUaM9fugKnQL1V6zQp5TbPmopipiH
I am trying to add the metadata to the newly created SPL Token using the following command.
spl-token initialize-metadata 2ePFwPK3coTPqzirUaM9fugKnQL1V6zQp5TbPmopipiH NALA NALA ipfs://QmVmSfUfY36NtjgR621FhWQUwrsDt9Uif2ymvpt5rA4dEx

It is throwing the following error.
Error: Program(InvalidAccountData)

Could you please guide me to understand this issue.

Since you're using the spl-token CLI, then the metadata that you're trying to create is specific to spl-token-2022.
To create the metadata then, you first need to create a mint with spl-token-2022 using the --enable-metadata flag:
$ spl-token --program-id TokenzQdBNbLqP5VEhdkAS6EPFLC1PHnBqCXEpPxuEb create-token --enable-metadata

After that, you can initialize the metadata:
$ spl-token initialize-metadata <MINT_ADDRESS> MyTokenName TOKEN http://my.token

But be sure to use a mint address. In your case, 2ePFwPK3coTPqzirUaM9fugKnQL1V6zQp5TbPmopipiH is a user's token account, and FgWD6aipxESGpEAdm4fBCipMMiV38TQfWbR5Lree6LkN is the mint account.
More information at https://spl.solana.com/token-2022/extensions#metadata
